# talend open studio create tmap

Tags: talend, tmap

I want to select certain columns from 2 tables by coding the appropriate SQL code in the "query" zone of my tMySQLInput component. Then I've been told to use a "tMap" component in order to map each column from my tMySQLInput component to my tMySQLOutput component.

Is this the correct way to to do what I need to do : Take information (SELECT ...) from 2 tables and then insert them into another 3 rd table?

Comment: Googled it, got results for exactly this. Example 1: https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-tmap-component-reference.html example 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20qJmOr5Uts example 3: https://mindmajix.com/talend/creating-tmap-expressions-using-tmap-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to insert data from 2 tables (source) into another table(target), it is necessary to use tmap component.

1.`tMysqlinput(with query)` and check the edit schema section for appropriate values you wish to send to the output/target

2.`tMap` component map all the necessary columns from source to target

3.`tMysqlOutput` check the edit schema section for appropriate columns that you wish to see in your target.